# Cleaner way to represent languages accepted by DFAs?

Tags: formal-languages

I am given 2 DFAs. * denotes final states and -> denotes the initial state, defined over the alphabet {a, b}.

1) ->A with a goes to A. -> A with b goes to *B. *B with a goes to *B. *B with b goes to ->A.

The regular expression for this is clearly:
E = a* b(a* + (a* ba* ba*)*)

And the language that it accepts is L1= {w over {a,b} | w is b preceeded by any number of a's followed by any number of a's or w is b preceeded by any number of a's followed by any number of bb with any number of a's in middle of(middle of bb), end or beginning.}

2) ->* A with b goes to ->* A. ->*A with a goes to *B. *B with b goes to ->* A. *B with a goes to C. C with a goes to C. C with b goes to C.

Note: A is both final and initial state. B is final state.

Now the regular expression that I get for this is:

E = b* ((ab) * + a(b b* a)*)

Finally the language that this DFA accepts is:
L2 = {w over {a, b} | w is n 1's followed by either k 01's or a followed by m 11^r0' s where n,km,r >= 0}

Now the question is, is there a cleaner way to represent the languages L1 and L2 because it does seem ugly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: define 'cleaner'

Comment: Hey Jason, just some pattern in the RE that I might have missed.

Answer (score 0):

```
E = a* b(a* + (a* ba* ba*)*)
  = a*ba* + a*b(a* ba* ba*)*
  = a*ba* + a*b(a*ba*ba*)*a*
  = a*b(a*ba*ba*)*a*
  = a*b(a*ba*b)*a*
```

This is the language of all strings of `a` and `b` containing an odd number of `b`s. This might be most compactly denoted symbolically as `{w in {a,b}* | #b(w) = 1 (mod 2)}`.

For the second one: the only way to get to state B is to see an `a` in `A`, and the only way to get to `C` from outside `C` is to see an `a` in `B`. `C` is a dead state and the only way to get to it is to see `aa` starting in `A`. That is: if you ever see two `a`s in a row, the string is not in the language; the language is the set of all strings over `a` and `b` not containing the substring `aa`. This might be most compactly denoted symbolically as `{(a+b)*aa(a+b)*}^c` where `^c` means "complement".